# ROS integration with SMACH

Tags: xml, integrate, publisher, subscriber, ros

I am currently developing a GUI using QT that changes based on an XML string it receives from a ROS message being sent from another QT GUI. This is working fine however I need to create a node using ROS and SMACH that will send different XML strings to the GUI based on what state the SMACH state machine is in.

I have no experience with SMACH and have been unable to find a good example of how to integrate a ROS Publisher and Subscriber with a SMACH state machine.

Any examples or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there should be a visualizer with ros (`rosrun smach_visualizer smack_visualizer.py` or something like that should  start it). Maybe you can find it's source take a look at that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this - it should contain everything you need

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)